# Is LHV or HHV used for calculating the thrust of a jet engine?

Tags: jet-engine

[Lower and Higher Heat Values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_of_combustion#Higher_heating_value) (LHV or HHV) seem to have multiple definitions based on things I can't figure out.

What I want to know is, which one is appropriate to use for calculating the thrust from a jet engine? I'm thinking of large commercial turbofan engines like on the 747 or A380.

Also, since water vapor seems to have something to do with it, what about jet engines that run on hydrogen like the experimental [Tu-155](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-155)? Should we use LHV or HHV to calculate thrust in those engines?

Comment: Use _for what_? Those are just numbers that describe the fuel.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more about thermodynamic calculations than aviation and as such is better suited for http://physics.stackexchange.com/. After clarification what you want to use the specific heat of combustion for.

Comment: On a side note, fuel suppliers usually use the lower heat values. It then leads to paradoxes like natural gas boilers with 109% efficiency.

Comment: @JanHudec I'm not sure what is unclear. I want to use it for jet engines, for thrust.

Comment: Well, the thrust _just is_. It is generated by burning the fuel, not by chewing up numbers! You don't need to use numbers for it. Now if you want to _calculate thrust_, that's another matter, but you didn't say that.

Comment: Now that we've established that you want to _calculate thrust_, you can use **either**! You just have to be aware of their definition and of the fact, that the water is still in gaseous phase and include specific heat of evaporation or not as appropriate for the heating value you use.

Comment: @JanHudec yes I want to calculate thrust. I honestly don't understand what else you're saying. Thrust and pretty much everything else obeys natural laws. I want to know which law is at work, one involving HHV or one involving LHV.

Comment: If you were instead calculating _efficiency_, you'd get different efficiency for different definitions of heating values. And while it's the LHV-based one that is normally used, the HHV-based one arguably makes more sense. But for thrust (via heat of the combustion gas) you can use either definition, if you use appropriate equation.

Comment: For calculating thrust in the usual manner using some energy balance across the combustion chamber, the LHV needs to be used. I think that is pretty simple and straightforward and Peter Kämpf answered it well.

Comment: @JanHudec Why does the HHV make more sense to you? Unless the device has a way to condense the water vapor evolved how is the HHV equivalent energy ever accessible in an aircraft type jet engine?

Comment: @JanHudec Do you have a link or any more info about the 109% boiler efficiency case you cited? Just curious. Because to get 109% based on LHV the natural gas boiler would have to be a condensing type. Do such boilers exist in typical use? I'm used to coal fired boilers and ours tend to be in the 88% efficiency range, again based on the LHV.

Comment: @curious_cat: Yes, a condensing type. Yes, they exist. I have such thing at home. Basically in last maybe 10 years if you needed a new one, there is little point in not getting a condensing type. I believe the 109% was mentioned in the specs as maximum under favourable conditions, but I can't quickly find English Junkers page (their .com domain is in German).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference between both values is the energy set free when the water created by the combustion process condenses. Use the lower heat value for jet engine calculations. The water in a jet engine leaves it as vapor, and the vaporisation heat is lost for propulsion.